# Get url of iframe or check if url contains

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I have an iframe to a third party website (different domain) where users complete a form to sign up. Within the iframe, the user completes a form, then see's a 'confirm your details' screen and finally a success screen.

The success screen url ends with `/success`

I want to show a 'complete' button on my site, only after they see this success message.

Is there a simple way that I can achieve this? Possibly by checking if the iframe URL ends with `/success`?

Comment: No, that is not possible from your end alone, the Same Origin Policy is in place to prevent any such thing. This can only work if the 3rd party you embed the widget from actively supports it, for example by providing a script API that uses postMessage to be able to communicate across different origins.